# Making a song name out of a URL

Tags: java, android

I have a URL and I want it to look like this:

```
Action Manatee - Action

http://xxxxxx.com/songs2/Music%20Promotion/Stream/Action%20Manatee%20-%20Action.mp3
```

What is the syntax for trimming up to where it after this "Stream/" and make spaces where the %20 is. I also want to trim the .mp3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, for that particular example, I would split the string according to the '/' character then trim the text that follows the final '.' character. Finally, do a replace of "%20" into " ". That should leave you with the string you want

### Tested

```
String initial = "http://xxxxxx.com/songs2/Music%20Promotion/Stream/Action%20Manatee%20-%20Action.mp3";

String[] split = initial.split("/");

String output = split[split.length-1];

int length = output.lastIndexOf('.');
output = output.substring(0, length);
output = output.replace("%20", " ");
```

Comment: As I recall, string.split uses a regex as opposed to a literal string, I believe that you need .split("\/") as opposed to .split("/")

Comment: @Rionmonster: Oh, well I ran that code against a unit test and it worked so apparently its not essential.

Comment: Just thought that I would let you know - interesting to find out that it isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `split()` and `replace(`) methods to accomplish this, here are two ways:

**Split your string apart by using the forward slashes:**

```
string yourUrl = [URL Listed];

//Breaks your URL into sections on slashes
string[] sections = yourUrl.split("\/"); 

//Grabs the last section after the slashes, and replaces the %20 with spaces
string newString = sections[sectiongs.length-1].replace("%20"," ");
```

**Split your string at the Stream/ section**: *(Only use this if you can guarantee it will be in that form)*

```
string yourUrl = [URL Listed];

//This will get everything after Stream (your song name)
string newString = yourUrl.split("Stream\/")[1]; 

//Replaces your %20s with spaces
newString = newString.replace("%20"," ");
```

Comment: it will always be in this form

Answer (score 0):

```
String urlParts[] = URL.split("\/");
String urlLast = urlParts[length-1];
String nameDotMp = urlLast.replaceAll("%20");
String name = nameDotMp.substring(0,nameDotMp.length-5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
URL songURL = new URL("yourpath/filename");
String filename = songURL.getFile();
```